# jquery / Regex, stop event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a form validation using jquery /regex:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.keyup-numeric').keyup(function () {
        $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
        if (!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $(this).after('<span class="tiny warning_bubble">Numeric characters only.</span>');
        }

    });
});
```

How can I stop the warning_bubble span from piling up?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M2Ns5/
THanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the warning created with the rest of the html, and set its style to be initially hidden and then just show, or hide the warning when needed

HTML

```
<label>Phone Number:
   <input type="tel" class="keyup-numeric" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX"/>
   <span class="tiny warning_bubble">Numeric characters only.</span>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.warning_bubble {
     color:#d2232a;
     -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color:#ffdd97;
    padding:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.keyup-numeric').keyup(function () {
        $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
        if (!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $(this).parent().find(".warning_bubble").show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find(".warning_bubble").hide();
        }

    });
});
```

<kbd>**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M2Ns5/1)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Check if the next element has the `warning_bubble` class & then add it the span.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.keyup-numeric').keyup(function () {
        $('span.error-keyup-1').hide();
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
        if (!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {
            if (!$(this).next().hasClass('warning_bubble')) {
                $(this).after('<span class="tiny warning_bubble">Numeric characters only.</span>');
            }
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find(".warning_bubble").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddleDemo here](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu18mhyd/baTgn/)**

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/PkPU9/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function(tel) {
        // Validation expression
        var numericReg = /^\d*\d(|.\d*\d|,\d*\d)?$/;
        // Create bubble
        var bubble = $('<span class="tiny warning_bubble" style="display:none">Numeric characters only.</span>');
        $(tel).after(bubble); // Add and hide bubble to the input
       // Add key listener to the text input
        $(tel).keyup(function () {
            var inputVal = $(this).val();
            // Toggle the bubble using jquery show/hide
            bubble[inputVal && !numericReg.test(inputVal) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
        });
    })('.keyup-numeric');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The fewest changes to your code would be to add a container inside the label, after the input:

```
<span class="warning-container"></span>
```

And change your after line to a empty/append:

```
$(this).siblings('.warning-container').empty().append('<span class="tiny warning_bubble">Numeric characters only.</span>');
```

---

***Note:** `empty().append()` is a faster way of doing `html()`.  Also be aware that while this is the fewest changes to your original code, there are many ways to make it more efficient and more robust.*